# How to keep the flashlight on (programmatically) while the camera preview is ON

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight

So for my Android app, I have created a `SurfaceView` and assigned it as camera preview and start camera preview using the necessary API's. But now I want to turn the Flashlight ON (kind of act like a Torch) while the preview is working.

Please note that I have seen tons of examples online on how to turn flashlight on and it works as long as I don't call the open camera API. Below is the code -

```
try
{
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
    if (cameraManager != null)
    {
        //for the sake of brevity, hardcoded the camera id. 0 is mostly back camera
        cameraManager.SetTorchMode(0, true); 
    }
}
catch (CameraAccessException e)
{
   LogUtil.Error("CameraInput", e.ToString());
}
```

Please note I am testing on Android N and hence the above code works flawlessly. But as soon as I call below line of code, the flash turns off.

```
Camera camera = Camera.Open(0);
// ...... some code  ....//
camera.StartPreview();
```

When the above 2 lines execute, the flash goes off. Is this a know behaviour like where camera takes exclusive lock over flash hardware and resets it's value to default.

I tried reversing the above code i.e calling the Camera Open API being called first and then setting the flash. On that I get `CameraAccessException` , camera already in use.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this while previewing on `SurfaceView`

```
params = camera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Remember that **If you want to use it as flashlight you can do:**

```
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

If not, to turn flash on which will come out when you take the picture, you use:

```
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: I exactly tried this yesterday but definitely I missed something because it did not work then. But since your answer, I gave a go again and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to torch on and off while camera is previewing. On button click to on/off the light, use this code:

```
//at some other function where camera is initialised and start preview
//...
Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.startPreview();
//...
boolean lightOn = false;
//...

buttonLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

                if (!lightOn) {
                    lightOn = true;
                    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                } else {
                    lightOn = false;
                    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                }
        }
    });
```

Happy Coding! :D